# Does "zusammen" imply "mit mir" in an invitation?

Tags: english-to-german, usage

In English, if you want to invite someone to accompany you somewhere, you can use the word "together", as in "together with me". Can *zusammen* be used the same way in German? For example, if I want to ask someone to join me on a trip, in English I might ask

> Do you want to go on holiday together?

Is it then correct in German to ask

> "Willst du zusammen in den Urlaub fahren?"

Comment: What's your specific concern here? Which part seems problematic to you?

Comment: I don’t honk that the recent edit, not by the OP, represents the situation in English correctly

Comment: @Carsten S -- Yes, that expression is probably only used colloquially and I'd be hard pressed to prove it in a dictionary. See [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/8f8asw/if_i_ask_a_girl_hey_do_you_want_to_get_lunch/) for an example though. I might have thought it's an American thing, but Americans say "go on vacation", not "go on holiday", so we can say that OP is not an American. And I explained in another comment why I think it's the only likely interpretation of the example sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In German, other than in English, "zusammen" does not automatically imply "with me" if the with ... part is omitted. You'll have to add that explicitly:

> Willst du **mit mir** zusammen in den Urlaub fahren?

or

> **Wollen wir** zusammen in den Urlaub fahren?

Otherwise, the sentence is grammatically correct, it just doesn't make much sense in German to use "zusammen" with a singular subject without stating with whom.

Comment: thank you this is really helpful

Answer (score 5):

Grammatically? That sentence is correct.

Semantically? It would definitely receive more than one raised eybrow.

"Du" is a single person. Without mentioning someone else, your sentence immediately would receive a "zusammen? Mit wem?" response.

*Wollt ihr zusammen in den Urlaub fahren?*

*Willst du zusammen mit deinem Freund in den Urlaub fahren?*

would fix this.

Comment: I guess in English when you say "together" it implies "with me" if there are no other people mentioned. Basically, the most likely interpretation is that you are inviting someone to accompany you on your vacation/holiday. It could be the plural you, but I don't see how that might happen; are you a travel agent, marriage councilor, matchmaker maybe? Assuming the "with me", I think it would be better to just drop the *zusammen* and go with *Willst du mit mir in den Urlaub fahren?*

Comment: @RDBury Yes I should gave clarified I meant "with me" thank you!

Comment: @AliceDent: please edit your question so that your clarification gets included. Thanks.

Comment: @Alice Dent -- One of the unexpected challenges of learning a new language is learning to telli the difference between the literal meaning and the implied meaning of words in your own language. I suggest re-editing the question to focus on the zussamen issue alone and use the sentence you gave and it's intended meaning as an example. I might do it myself if you don't want to. Sometimes questions are closed unfairly here, but I think it was justified in this case. Ideally, a question asks something that someone else might to find out about as well. Translation checking doesn't do that.